# Build URL in other MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 MVC websites (and a common library).

In project 'A' i need a URL from project 'B'.  In Project 'B' I can use Url.Action("Method", "Controller") to build up the URL.

How would I be able to reference a route from another project across websites?
And what about unit testing?

Comment: Put your controllers in a separate project which you can then reference ?

Comment: I wan't clear enough I think.  I don't need to have the route twice.  I need to reference from one project to a route in the other project.    Sharing the controllers in a separate project might does not expose the right route from the other project.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Put your RouteConfig class where you define your routes in the Common library, then in the Global.asax files of both websites call the RegisterRoutes method on that class.